# Laravel is remembering past/dropped tables when using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

Basically,

I'm running this in `php artisan tinker`

```
$article = new App/articles;
$article->article_name = "My Story";
$article->article_content = "Today was a good day..";

$article->save();
```

The last statement `$article->save()` throws a Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message

> SQLSTATE[42S22]:Column not found: Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `articles` (`article_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Which basically tries to insert data into an **old table/model** of the same name which i had created and dropped from mysql.

Why Does Laravel keep remembering the old table column details?

Is there a way i can flush this memory?

I've tried `php artisan cache:clear` but that does'nt seem to clear this particular type of cache

Comment: Does your article model have a `public $timestamps = false;`?

Comment: @MarkBaker probably in the old article model. The one i've deleted and dropped. but not in the new one

Comment: You said that you'd deleted the old table from MySQL, not that you'd modified the model

Comment: @MarkBaker I've edited, sorry

Comment: Are you running PHP with OpCache enabled? That might cache the old model

Answer (score 0):

The `created_at` and `updated_at` columns are used by Eloquent by default, you need to disable this functionality by setting the `$timestamps` property on your model to false.

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    protected $timestamps = false;

}
```